# I have included a template function declaration in a header file and the defintion of the function is written in the .cpp file

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have declared a template function in .h file and defined in a .cpp file and calling the function from another .cpp file.

i am getting the following error

/tmp/ccJg5vwy.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to`short temp < int, std::allocator < int > >(std::__cxx11::list > const&)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

my files are:

//main.cpp

```
#include"a.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    list<int> arr(5);
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        arr.push_back(i);
    fun1();
    fun2();
    temp(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

//a.h

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;
void fun1();
void fun2();
template <class L ,class A>
    short temp(const list<L,A>& val);
```

//fun2.cpp

```
#include"a.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun2(){
    cout<<"I am in function2\n";
}
```

//a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun1()
{
        cout<<"I am in function1\n";
}
template <class L,class A>
    short temp(const list<L,A>& val){
        cout<<"inside the template function\n";
        typename list<L,A>::const_iterator iter=val.begin();
         while (iter != val.end())
                {
                       cout<< *iter << endl;
                       ++iter;
                }
         cout<<"leaving the template function\n";
            return 0;
    }
```

and i am compiling the files in the following format

g++ a.cpp fun2.cpp main.cpp

I am not getting why there is a linking problem.

I have also tried by changing a.cpp and a.h to the following format but still i am getting the error

//a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun1()
{
    cout<<"I am in function1\n";
}
template <class L>
    short temp(const list<L>& val){
        cout<<"inside the template function\n";
        typename list<L>::const_iterator iter=val.begin();
        while (iter != val.end())
                {
                       cout<< *iter << endl;
                       ++iter;
                }
         cout<<"leaving the template function\n";
            return 0;
    }
```

//a.h

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;
void fun1();
void fun2();
template <class L>
short temp(const list<L>& val);
```

in this case error is

/tmp/cce0eJj9.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to`short temp< int >(std::__cxx11::list > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You can not declare template functions in  header and define in .cpp. Only in headers or include .cpp after declare.

Comment: @MrBin: Yes you can. But it's a bit of a complicated matter. See the linked answers.

Comment: @SebastianMach,  i wrote the same thing at the end.

Comment: @MrBin: The same as what? I just wrote "see the linked answers". And including source files is the same as including header files. If you're funny, you can also name it "foo.h" and "foo.frob". The compiler does not principally differentiate header files from source files. The key points to understand are ODR (One Definition Rule) explicit instantiation.